# Webstorm Intellisense in .cshtml files

Tags: java, .net, webstorm

I can't figure a way to get Webstorm v7 to give me intellisense for JavaScript while in a .cshtml file (ASP.NET MVC).  Is there a way to enable that?

Comment: I am sorry, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I am getting JavaScript autocompletion for *.cshtml files in WebStorm like this:

[image: Autocompletion in cshtml]

All I did was to register '*.cshtml' as html files under Settings | Editor | File Types
See: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/file-types.html

Comment: It didn't do anything in my case. How did you set it up exactly?

Answer (score 4):

My answer is almost same as above.
Basically, in windows you go into Files > Settings > Editor > File Types >  for eg: Recognized File Types - HTML and then in the window below +(add) and add *.cshtml

It still won't recognize your ASP.NET MVC syntax but HTML syntax, it will.

[image: Webstorm Settings Window]